# Why can't the Klein-4 group be generated by a single element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

This is stated in my notes, but with no proof to back it up and I can't seem to figure it out. Could someone please explain?

Comment: There are just four elements. You simply check that each element cannot generate the whole group alone.

Comment: @edm Wow can't believe I didn't think of that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Klein-4 group, each element squares to the identity element.  Thus the orders of the elements are 1 (for the identity) or 2 (for everything else).  So nothing generates all 4 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Because it can't?  The identity generates only one element, and the other three elements generate only themselves and the identity.  So, no element generates all four.  You simply check it.